# Remove bounding rect with an area < n OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, bounding-box

I am eroding an image with text blocks on it then using `findContours()` to find all of the text blocks, then drawing their bounding rect. However sometimes there are very small rects created by noise in the image which either are in a bigger rect or in a place where there is no text.

I am using this code to find the contours and draw them.

```
double element_size = 20;
RNG rng(12345);
Mat element = getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,cv::Size( 2*element_size + 1, 2*element_size+1 ),cv::Point( element_size, element_size ) );
erode(quad, quad, element);
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
quad.convertTo(quad, CV_8UC1);
findContours( quad, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<cv::Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
}

Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( quad.size(), CV_8UC3 );
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    Scalar color = Scalar(0,255, 0 );
    rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
}
```

After a sample run here is what I get back:

[image]

How can I modify my code so that I can remove any rects that are not greater than `n` so I can only keep complete text blocks, I also need to remove the largest contour which surrounds the entire card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a safer method of removing `cv::Rect` elements from your `vector`, you could use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove the elements which are below a certain area threshold. This method is *much* safer than deleting elements one-by-one by their index, as in Haris' answer, since you do not risk running off the end of the vector.

```
boundRect.erase(std::remove_if(boundRect.begin(), boundRect.end(),
                               [] (cv::Rect r)
                               {
                                   const int min_area = 100;
                                   return r.area() < min_area;
                               }), boundRect.end());
```

Here I use a C++11 lambda for the comparison. If you don't have C++11, it's easy enough to create a functor class instead.

As for removing the largest contour, you can use another function from the standard library, [max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) (Again using a lambda for comparison):

```
boundRect.erase(std::max_element(boundRect.begin(), boundRect.end(),
                                 [] (cv::Rect left, cv::Rect right)
                                 {
                                     return left.area() < right.area();
                                 }));
```

Comment: So will that first code snippet remove all the rects that are below `min_area`? I am not very familiar with these features of C++11.

Comment: When using the code snippets after the `for loop` that contains `boundRect[i]` It did not seem to remove any of the very small contours, I played with the threshold and it did not affect the results. And for removing the largest contour it did not seem to do so. Any idea?

Comment: @Nick Yes, the first snippet does as you expect. For your second comment, I can't say why you are getting unexpected results without seeing  your updated code. Perhaps edit it into your question or ask a new one. I did notice your second `for` loop has a bug. Your iteration limit is `contours.size()`, but it should really be `boundRect.size()`, since `boundRect` will be shorter than `contours`, you again risk out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I fixed the bug in the for loop. I found out that I needed a very high min area for what I am doing. `15000` Thanks for the code snippets!

Answer (score 3):

Yo could use [contourArea](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) to eliminate contour, use below code before finding bounding rect, this will remove all the contour with area less than a threshold.

```
double min_area=100; // area threshold

 for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour.
 {
   double area=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
   if(area<min_area)
    contours.erase(contours.begin() + i);
 }
```

**Edit:-**

For any one who is going to use the above code, please see  below comment.

Comment: It is not safe to erase items from or insert items into C++ `std::vector` during a for-loop the way done in your code. You have three choices: (1) Iterate backwards, so that a deletion of item does not cause the index of yet-to-be-processed items to shift; (2) To copy the items which you intend to keep into a new `vector`, or (3) to store the boolean result in a separate vector of flags, so that the next time you can use both vectors to filter out items.